# Shortcode - Display product price by product SKU in Woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, price

I need to display the price of a given product by using sku , trying to do it with few shortcodes i have found but not much luck - would like to view the price on the page after entering a product's sku into the shortcode, like this
[woocommerce_price sku="sku123"]
[woocommerce_price sku="sku345"]

anyone would be able to advise how to achieve that?

see here for an example code i tried but doesnt work

````
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'sku' => null,
    ), $atts, 'woocommerce_price' ) );
    
    if( intval( $sku ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
          $product = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
          
          if ( $product->get_price() > 0 ) {
              return $product->get_price_html();
          } else {
              return __( "Price unavailable", "woocommerce" );
          }
     }
}
add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_price', 'wc_price_shortcode_callback' );```
````

Comment: [wc_get_product_id_by_sku](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_get_product_id_by_sku) returns an integer (id of) not the product itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function and get price

```html
function get_product_by_sku( $sku ) {
    
    global $wpdb;

    $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );

    if ( $product_id ) return new WC_Product( $product_id );

    return null;}
    

$product = get_product_by_sku( $sku);

$product->get_regular_price();
$product->get_sale_price();
$product->get_price();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the inner shortcode code after your extract.

```
if( !is_null($sku) && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
      $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );

      $product = wc_get_product($product_id); //get the product object from id here.
      
      if ( $product->get_price() > 0 ) {
          return $product->get_price_html();
      } else {
          return __( "Price unavailable", "woocommerce" );
      }
 }
```